# file send to browser: filename equal scriptname instead defined name

Tags: php, file, header

when i send a csv file to the browser using header('Content-Disposition: attachment filename="xyz.cs" '); the file named as export.php (filename of the php-script) instead of xyz.csv

```
public function sendCSV($arrBody, $arrHeadings)
{
    $fh = fopen('php://output', 'w');

    ob_start();

    fputcsv($fh, $arrHeadings);

    if (! empty($arrBody)) {
        foreach ($arrBody as $line) {
            fputcsv($fh, $line);
        }
    }

    $strBuffer = ob_get_clean();

    $strFile = 'csv_' . date('Ymd') . '-' . uniqid() . '_export.csv';

    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Cache-Control: private",false);
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment filename=\"$strFile\";" );
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

    exit($strBuffer);
}
```

Comment: You are missing a semicolon: `header("Content-Disposition: attachment; [<-------this one] filename=\"$strFile\";" );`

Comment: Besides that remove the `\"` around `$strFile`

Comment: oh waia... that hurt... and took hours, thanks!